# azure-devops-extension-api - Run pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

I'm trying to run a pipeline from an Azure DevOps hub extension, using the [azure-devops-extension-api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-devops-extension-api/?view=azdevops-ext-latest).

The [azure-devops-extension-api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-devops-extension-api/?view=azdevops-ext-latest) ([GitHub repository](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-extension-api)) contains several rest client classes, such as the [BuildRestClient class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-devops-extension-api/buildrestclient?view=azdevops-ext-latest) and the [ReleaseRestClient class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-devops-extension-api/releaserestclient?view=azdevops-ext-latest). Both of which I've successfully used methods from.

However, the [azure-devops-extension-api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-devops-extension-api/?view=azdevops-ext-latest) doesn't contain any rest client class for the [Runs - Run Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run%20pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) Azure DevOps Services REST API. I'm suspecting that this is because this endpoint is new for the 6.0 version of the API, and so it hasn't been implemented in the [azure-devops-extension-api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-devops-extension-api/?view=azdevops-ext-latest) yet

Is there any way that I could use this [azure-devops-extension-api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-devops-extension-api/?view=azdevops-ext-latest) to run a specified pipeline?
Perhaps via the [queueBuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-devops-extension-api/buildrestclient?view=azdevops-ext-latest#queuebuild-build--string--boolean--string--number-) method? I want to run a specific pipeline though, not a specific old build.

Any input would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing, was creating my own PipelineClient class (from the [Runs - Run Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run%20pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)), which extends the RestClientBase from the azure-devops-extension-api/Common/RestClientBase.

Thankful for the input I got to this question, it's appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you want to use azure-devops-extension-api to run a specified pipeline, you can use [queueBuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-devops-extension-api/buildrestclient?view=azdevops-ext-latest#queuebuild-build--string--boolean--string--number-) method.

Regarding the `sourceBuildId` parameter, there is no specific description in the document, I will add it here.

`sourceBuildId`: The source build must be a pull request build if queueing with `sourceBuildId`.

Comment: Thank you for this input, Hugh. Appreciate it.